# Typesetting pullbacks - tweaking `underset`

Tags: spacing, positioning

From time to time I want typeset a `×` symbol underset with `f,g`. The output command `\underset{f,g}{\times}` is a little clumsy for me.

How can I typeset something which looks more like the expression on the right below?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps the `\scriptbelow` macro of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/169603/15925, possibly with `\scriptscriptsize` instead of `\scriptsize` does what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `stackengine` package allows stacks to be highly customized.  Here, I set in the preamble 3 things:

1. stacks are processed in math mode
2. the width of the understacked material will not affect the spacing of the "anchor" (in this case, `\times`)
3. the gap between the anchor and the stacked material will be `0pt`

Because the stack is a wrapper around its content, the `\times` loses its `\mathbin` characteristic relative to the `A`s.  That seemed to be what the OP desired; however, it can always be added back manually around the stack.

The MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\renewcommand\useanchorwidth{T}
\setstackgap{S}{0pt}
\begin{document}
$A\stackunder{\times}{\scriptscriptstyle f\cdot g} A$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, this can all be wrapped up into a macro.  Here, I show it with the `\mathbin` nature of `\times` restored.  I call the macro `\quork{}{}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\renewcommand\useanchorwidth{T}
\setstackgap{S}{0pt}
\newcommand\quork[2]{\mathbin{\stackunder{#1}{\scriptscriptstyle #2}}}
\begin{document}
$A\quork{\times}{f\cdot g} A$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't read the details, just the image, and it struck me. I'll remove my useless comment.

Comment: @Bernard It was a good comment; I edited further to make use of it.

Answer (score 3):

I think  there's an optical illusion, due to the ascender in `f`. You can correct it with a negative thin space. I also suggest another possible layout, with the ‘index’ slightly on the right of ×. In the following code, I defined two commands for these:`\pullback` and `\varpullbback`:

```
 \documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand\pullback[1]{\underset{\mathclap{#1}}{\times}}
\newcommand\varpullback[1]{\times_{\clap{\raisebox{-1.2ex}{$\scriptstyle #1 $}}}\mkern-1mu}

\begin{document}

\[ A \pullback{\!f\mkern-2.5mu, g}B\qquad A \varpullback{f\mkern-2.5mu, g}B\]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The kerning or lack of it between the *f* and the comma doesn't help with the optical illusion.

Comment: @Chris H: You're right, but that can't be automated. I've added some negative kerning in the argument to compensate.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a version based on the idea of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/169603/15925:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand*{\sunderbin}[3][0pt]{%
  \mathbin{\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{0}%
    \begin{array}[t]{@{}c@{}}%
      #3\\[{#1}]%
      \mathclap{\scriptstyle #2}%
    \end{array}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  A \underset{f,g}{\times} B
  \qquad
  A \sunderbin{f,g}{\times} B
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

There is an optional argument to increase the space between the operator and the subscripts.